# How do you write 5000 in scientific notation/standard form?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

My first thought was $5.0*10^3$, but the first zero is not significant here.
Should the answer be $0.5*10^4$?

Comment: $5\times10^3$ is correct. The mantissa has to be in $[1,10)$.

Comment: Great, I didn't think of dropping the decimal point. Is that standard practice or your opinion?

Comment: IMO both are correct, and the digits after the decimal point indicate the precision.

Comment: When there's only one significant digit, the decimal point may be dropped. For example, if your 5000 was measured to 2 sf you would put $5.0\times10^3$.

Comment: Great, how do I accept your answer Parcly Taxel? I seem to be only able to vote it useful.

Comment: Comments can't be accepted as answers unless the person commenting rewrites it as an answer. You can upvote his comment.

Comment: Fair enough, Parcly Taxel answered my question but I will give my acceptance to tomi who was also useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How accurately have you measured?

If you know that your answer is correct to the nearest whole number, then you should write $5.000 \times 10^3$

If you know that your answer is correct to the nearest ten, then you should write $5.00 \times 10^3$

If you know that your answer is correct to the nearest hundred, then you should write $5.0 \times 10^3$

If you know that your answer is correct to the nearest thousand, then you should write $5 \times 10^3$

If you know that your answer is correct to the nearest 0.1, then you should write $5.0000 \times 10^3$